# Is it possible to install TOR without root access

Tags: root, tor

i have ssh access to a linux  box running ubuntu server 12.04
I need to install tor to configure it as a TOR relay however i do not have root access . How can i do this . i have tried compiling but my methods have failed

Can someone post a descriptive guide on

1. Installing TOR without root access
2. Configuring it to run automatically ( like a cronjob etc..)

Comment: Provided that files in a folder writable by your user can be executed, that your user does not have a ridiculous process limit, then anything that listens on ports above 1024 can be installed (or compiled) and run by a non super users.

Comment: i have rw acess to my personal folder no process limit  however only ports 80 and 22 are open. can you post the instructions  for compling please

Comment: https://www.torproject.org/download/download: Configure with: ./configure && make && src/or/tor You're likely to run into trouble if this is your first time. Try reading some intro like http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/softinstall.html

Comment: Ok i got the source package then  during ./configure i got an error as libevent was not present then i got it and complied it  currently libevent is inside the tor/libevent directory but for the TOR ./configure when i use the "--with-libevent-dir libevent" it still gives the error configure: WARNING: Could not find a linkable libevent.  If you have it installed somewhere unusual, you can specify an explicit path using --with-libevent-dir

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a support forum. For guidance on a specific problem, try posting in a "linux forum" or join a help channel on the IRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have the [deps already installed](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#source) and accessible as non-root, you should be able to install as non-root with the makefiles.  Using dpkg probably won't work because the admin locks you out of the pacakge db too.  :/

Specifying configure --prefix=/home/shenal/tor or -de -Dprefix=/home/shenal/tor or something similar (you would need to play around with the configure file a bit).  Then, again, assuming all the dependencies you need are accessible as non-root, just make && make install.

My bet, though, is that your admin has locked you out of some of the tools you will need to install.  Check out options like Joyent or Rackspace that give you more control, but they might not like you running a relay, and it could get expensive.  I have it set up out of my own house -- thanks to a progressive ISP (make sure you check with your ISP, or you could get an angry phone call, or a law suit, one day ...)